# Yahoo JSONP Ajax Request Wrapped in callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsonp, yahoo-api

I understand that I can make a crossdomain ajax call with jquery, .ajax, and jsonp. I am calling the yahoo stock quote api. Everything is working and the result is returning (I can see using Fiddler.) The problem is I get a js error YAHOO is undefined. I think its having problems because the JSON is formated within a callback function so its not correct json syntax. What can I do to fix it? Thanks! Here is the code:

```
     $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: 'callback',
            jsonpCallback: 'YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback',
            data:{
                query: request.term
            },
            url: 'http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc',
            success: function (data) {
                alert("yes");
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

I wanted to add this answer since it looks like [user209245's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071658/778581) above (which is from 2011) no longer works. Here's how I did it:

1. Use the [YQL Console](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol=%22AAPL%22) to build a query for the stock you want to get, e.g. Apple:

   > select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol="AAPL"
2. Make sure JSON is selected and specify a JSONP callback, e.g. `quote`
3. Click Test
4. Plug in the REST query that it generates for you like this:

   ```
   var quote;

   $(document).ready(function() {
       $.ajax({
           url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22AAPL%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=quote",
           dataType: "jsonp",
           jsonp: "callback",
           jsonpCallback: "quote"
       });

       quote = function(data) {
           $(".price").text("$" + data.query.results.quote.AskRealtime);
       };
   });
   ```

   Then on your page the `.price` `<div>` would display:

   ```
   $543.21
   ```

Of course, once you get the data back you can display anything you want; I'm just using price as an example since that's what I needed this for.

Comment: Just a quick tip for anyone else using this, make sure your `var quote;` is outside of the doc.ready function or else this doesn't work. At least that is what I found.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I got it to work:

I used .ajax instead of .jsonp because you need to give the url parameters.
You also need to define in your code the name of the Yahoo callback function.
Here is a link explaining how to use Yahoo callback function with its web services.

http://developer.yahoo.com/javascript/json.html#callbackparam

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // this variable must be defined this way
    var YAHOO = {
        Finance: {
            SymbolSuggest: {}
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(function(){           
        var query;

        query = 'Yahoo';        
        if (query.length > 0)
        {

          $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc",
              data: {query: query},
              dataType: "jsonp",
              jsonp : "callback",
              jsonpCallback: "YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback",
          });
          // call back function
          YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback = function (data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data));
          }
        }

    }); 


    </script>
```

Comment: Tried this just as you have it and it worked flawlessly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example : See the callback=? at the end of my query to make it work.
This example can be copied past as a standalone html .

https://github.com/cirs/PortfolioApp/blob/master/PortfolioApp-Step1-GetData.html

Comment: I get a 404 when hitting this url:http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?callback=?&query=a

Answer (score 0):

Here's an amended version that worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22AAPL%22)%0A%09%09&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=http%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltables.env&callback=quote",
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });

    window.quote = function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a js fiddle for this: 
https://jsfiddle.net/vham369w/1/

using `$.getJson` instead of `$.ajax`

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var symbol = 'AAPL'
    var url =  "https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%3D%22"+symbol+"%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys";
    $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $("#realtime").text("$" + data.query.results.quote.AskRealtime);
        $("#ask").text("$" + data.query.results.quote.Ask);
    });
});
```

HTML

```
Ask:
<div id="ask">
    loading ask
</div>
Realtime (null if market is closed):
<div id="realtime">
    loading realtime
</div>
```